# How would I splice and add these two char arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

I have this array.

```
char [] cornStrand = {'G','G','A','G','T','T','C','C','C','A'};
```

I also have this array, for which the values are inputted by the user running the program.

```
char [] bacteriaStrand = new char [5];

String strBases = scan.nextLine();

    for (int s=0; s <bacteriaStrand.length; s++)
    {
        char c = strBases.charAt(s);
        bacteriaStrand[s]= c ;
    }
```

The second block of code essentially inputs the values that the user entered into the bacteria strand array.

Now comes the tricky part. I need to "splice" and combine both arrays. By this I mean:

If the first character of

```
       char [] bacteriaStrand
```

is A, then I have to insert

```
  char [] bacteriaStrand
```

After the first G in

```
char [] cornStrand
```

Now, after I splice this, I have to put what I spliced into a new array, called

```
char [] combinedStrand
```

This is where I am becoming confused. If anyone can help, please do so! I would gladly appreciate it!

Comment: What have you tried?  This looks a lot like homework to me. SO is not a "Please do my homework" site.   A hint: First create the new  cominedStrand array, whose size will be the length of the corn + the length of bacteria.  Copy letters from corn strand over, until you come across g for the first time, then copy letters from the bacteria, and then continue with the rest of the corn.

Comment: @Daniel While this is my homework (partially), as you can see I did do a lot of the work. I tried many ways and it wasn't working, so THEN I turned to SO. Thanks for your suggestion though

Comment: @JoJo - We want you to >>show us<< that work; i.e. the code you have written.  It would be easy for us to simply write the code for you.  But that is counter-productive.  You need to do the programming yourself to learn. It is better if you show us what you have written so that we can either point out your mistakes or give you Hints on how to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do something like this:

```
public char[] combine(char[] bacteriaStrand, char[] cornStrand) {

        char[] result = new char[bacteriaStrand.length + cornStrand.length];

        if (bacteriaStrand[0] == 'A') {

            for (int i = 0; i < cornStrand.length; i++) {

                boolean insertedBacteria = false;

                if (cornStrand[i] == 'G') {

                    insertedBacteria = true;
                    for (int j = 0; j < bacteriaStrand.length; j++) {

                        result[i + 1 + j] = bacteriaStrand[j];

                    }
                    if (insertedBacteria)
                        i += bacteriaStrand.length;

                    result[i] = cornStrand[i];

                }

            }

        }

        return result;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is the only rule, it seems pretty simple to do.

```
if (bacteriaStrand[0] == 'A') {
    int totalLength = cornStrand.length + bacteriaStrand.length;
    char [] combinedStrand = new char [totalLength];
    for(int i=0; i<cornStrand.length; i++){
         combinedStrand[i] = cornStrand[i]; //fill in corn until you find the first G
         if (cornStrand[i] == 'G') {
            int j = 0;
            for(; j<bacteriaStrand.length; j++){
                combinedStrand[i+j+1] = bacteriaStrand[j]; //fill in bacteria
            }
            i++;
            for(;i<cornStrand.length;i++){
                combinedStrand[i+j+1] = cornStrand[i] //fill in the rest of corn
            }
         }                
    }//now this loop will break, since you increased i, so you won't get duplicates
}
```